# How can I register an auto-implemented repository located in a dependency as bean?

Tags: spring, dependency-injection, spring-data

I have a module `A` with a project dependency of module `B`:

**A's build.gradle**

```
dependencies {
  ....
  compile project(":B")
}
```

In module `B`, I have this interface:

```
@Repository
public interface MyRepo extends CrudRepository<User, String> {
    //some methods
}
```

In module `A`, I have this configuration class:

```
@Configuration
public class MyConfig {    

  @Bean
  public MyRepo provideMyRepo() {
      //???
  }

}
```

How can I export `MyRepo` bean in module `A`?

I have tried using `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableJpaRepositories`:

```
@Configuration
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = MyRepo.class)
public class MyConfig {    

  @Autowired
  public MyRepo myRepo;

}
```

But bean cannot be found:

> org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No
>   qualifying bean found for dependency

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can either `@EnableJpaRepositories` the package that `MyRepo` is contained in.

Or add a configuration is in Module `B` which will scan the required pacakges for the Repository for you and use the `Import` to pull the `Configuration` into `A`.

If it's a Spring Boot project you have the added functionality of Auto-configurations, https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-developing-auto-configuration.html

Finally, If the repository is already registered you can just use it as normal.

Comment: Where should I add @ComponentScan? In MyConfig class?

Comment: Yes in your config and provide the path as a paramater

Comment: Yeah, and point to the `MyRepo`, I would recommend using the `basePackagesClasses` attribute for safety.

Comment: Sorry, my bad you will likely need to use `@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackageClasses = MyRepo.class)` should hopefully work. May need to add `@EntitiyScan` too and scan the required entitiy.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need a new configuration for that repository since it is already registered with Spring. You can just inject it directly in your client classes in `A` module:

```
@Component
public class MyComponent {    
  @Inject
  private MyRepo myRepo;

  // your code using myRepo

}
```

If Spring says it can't find the bean, you need to check the autowiring configuration you have, so check that your scan path contain the repository class in `B` (change that using @ComponentScan or )

See [this example](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-autowire)